# A sequence of quadratic polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, quadratics

> Q. Let $p_n(x)=a_n x^2+b_n x$ be a sequence of quadratic polynomials where $a_n,b_n \in \Bbb R$ $\forall n \ge 1$. Let $\lambda_0$,$\lambda_1$ be distinct nonzero real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n(\lambda_0)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}p_n(\lambda_1)$ exist.
>
> Then,
>
> $1. \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(x)$ exists for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
>
> $2. \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n'(x)$ exists for all $x\in \Bbb R$.
>
> $3. \lim_{n\to \infty}p_n(\frac {\lambda_0+\lambda_1}2)$ does not exist.
>
> $4. \lim_{n\to \infty}p_n'(\frac {\lambda_0+\lambda_1}2)$ does not exist.

$p_n(\frac {\lambda_0+\lambda_1}2)=\frac {a_n}{4}(\lambda_0^2+\lambda_1^2)+\frac {b_n}{2} (\lambda_0+\lambda_1)+\frac {\lambda_0\lambda_1}2 \ldots\ldots (1)$

Also,

$p_n(\lambda_0)=a_n \lambda_0^2 +b_n \lambda_0 \ldots\ldots(2)$

and

$p_n(\lambda_1)=a_n \lambda_1^2 +b_n \lambda_1 \dots\ldots(3)$ which exist as $n \to \infty$ .

Hence $(1)$ exists as $n\to \infty$ (using $(2)$ and $(3)$) $\Rightarrow$ option 3 is false.

Option 4 seems to be true because $p_n'(\frac {\lambda_0+\lambda_1}2)=a_n \lambda_0+a_n \lambda_1+b_n$ and it is possible that $(b_n)$ may be divergent.

I have no idea about about options 1 and 2 :( Can you help?

Comment: 1 and 2 are true by what has been given.

Comment: @mathlover Please help me to see it.

Comment: Hint: Solve the system of equations $a_n\lambda_0^2+b_n\lambda_0=p_n(\lambda_0)$ and $a_n\lambda_1^2+b_n\lambda_1=p_n(\lambda_1)$ to have $a_n$ and $b_n$ in function of $p_n(\lambda_0)$ and $p_n(\lambda_1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_n=p_n(\lambda_0)$ and $v_n=p_n(\lambda_1)$. Then
$(u_n)$ converges to some limit $u$ and
$(v_n)$ converges to some limit $v$.

Then

$$
a_n\lambda_0^2+b_n\lambda_0=u_n, \ a_n\lambda_1^2+b_n\lambda_1=v_n \tag{1}
$$

Solving this $2\times 2$ system for $a_n,b_n$, we obtain

$$
a_n=\frac{-\lambda_1 u_n +\lambda_0 v_n}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)\lambda_0\lambda_1},
b_n=\frac{\lambda_1^2 u_n -\lambda_0^2 v_n}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)\lambda_0\lambda_1} \tag{2}
$$

whence

$$
p_n(x)=\frac{(-\lambda_1 u_n +\lambda_0 v_n)x^2+(\lambda_1^2 u_n -\lambda_0^2 v_n)x}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)\lambda_0\lambda_1} \tag{3}
$$

So that $(p_n(x))$ converges to $\frac{(-\lambda_1 u +\lambda_0 v)x^2+(\lambda_1^2 u-\lambda_0^2 v)x}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)\lambda_0\lambda_1}$. This shows that (1)
is true. Similarly (2) is true